# Facebook App : Error in the execution of Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I just begin the facebook development, and I try to make the first app with javascript SDK.

However, when I go the [page](http://yofitness.fr/share/fbtest.html) where I install the code, I have an error message saying that "does not work , try again later."

My application is in **development mode** and it's the good Appdata

In facebook dashboard I entered as **domain**: http://yofitness.fr

Someone have an idea ?

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '{624205284323943}',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });

        FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
          link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Assuming that's your actual appId, lose the curly braces (so just `appId: '624205284323943',...`).

Answer (score 1):

Change `appId:'{624205284323943}',` to `appId: '624205284323943',`